# What in the heyl is this thang?

Tags: ford, part-identification, sensor, van, econoline

I done bought me a mysterious 1998 5.4 v8 ford van.  Econoline series.

Done some snoopin under the hood and found this dang weird plastic box just hangin... danglin there zip tied to the dang high pressure side of the AC!  what in the heyl?

[image]

It's a funky plastic box with a cable leadin to it.  the cable has like a sorta "T-junction" in it that connects to a bigger more rubber cable (that I'm holdin in the picture)... kinda like youd expect like... a washer fluid cable to be.  The box got a sorta flat mounting piece with a hole in it prolly meant for a screw but I dont see anywheres it could be screwed to.

Here's a more closer up view for you:

[image]

...and here is where the little cable from it leads back to:

[image]

Surely this piece of Ford has a specific identity and is not a matter of opinion.

This puppy is a life or death matter for me, so please, somebody out there gotta know what it is.  Don't hold back.  (I hope it's not a cylinder head temperature sensor cuz it's measuring in the wrong place for sure).

Comment: Looks like a vacuum storage box, may not be the technical term, but it stores vacuum form the engine to operate vacuum operated devices in the car.

Comment: Does this van have cruise control, aftermarket or otherwise?

Comment: @Moab I'm thinking the same thing, I've seen them used for cruise control. Anyhow googling for <Vacuum Reservoirs 1998 Ford Econoline> brings up some pretty close looking pics. Looks to be originally mounted with plastic coming at a right angle out of the reservoir- likely snapped and was ziptied nearby.

Comment: Yes sir it does have a cruise control.  It works good.  Unless it is rainin real bad at the time you're cruisin... then the next day the gas pedal is sticky.

Comment: I found out what that box was.  But now I forgot again.